# WCF service hosted in one server working fine. hosted on another server giving error

Tags: wcf, service

I developed a WCF service with three methods. installed in my development server's IIS 6.0 and everything works just file. When I installed it on a production server's IIS 6.0 it's giving the following serialization error. I get the the same error when I try to run svcutil.exe

ms visual studio 2008, framework 3.5, IIS 6.0

contract: http://tempuri.org/:IOptiWeb ----> System.Runtime.Serialization.InvalidDataContractException: Type 'OptiWeb.GetResultRequestLineType' cannot be serialized. Consider marking it with the DataContractAttribute attribute, and marking all of its members you want serialized with the DataMemberAttribute attribute.
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContract.DataContractCriticalHelper.Throw InvalidDataContractException(String message, Type type)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContract.DataContractCriticalHelper.CreateDataContract(Int32 id, RuntimeTypeHandle typeHandle, Type type)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContract.DataContractCriticalHelper.GetDataContractSkipValidation(Int32 id, RuntimeTypeHandle typeHandle, Type type)

I am think it is something to do with the server security. Any help will be appreciated

Comment: more data must be given, what is the data contract, what are you trying to serialize ?

Comment: show OptiWeb.GetResultRequestLineType code

Comment: The problem has been resolved. One of the sub class didn't have the datacontract attribute. Once I added the attribute it started to work fine. thanks